# Try to modify the "Todo app"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm starting on ruby on rails, first thing I want to try is modifying the "Todo app" example.
I do this by the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fd1Vn-Wvy2w

After I finished, I saw that when I clicked on a `todo_list`, it will redirect to "`show`" form `todo_list`, but now I want the "`show`" display on the `index` with all the `todo_list`. I have tried to write

```
  <%= todo_items.content %>
```

on the `index` page but it got some errors. Is there any solution or should I modify something on the Controller page so that

`todo_items.content`

should be able to display on the `Index` page

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, skim through [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are we expected to watch the video to find out what the "Todo app" is?

Comment: just make sure that u know what app i concern about

Answer (score 2):

You need to load those items in your controller action first:

```
def index
  @todo_items = TodoItem.all
end
```

then in `index.html` or whatever template you are rendering for this action you can render this collection:

```
<%= render @todo_items %>
```

that should render an todo_item partial that you should have created based on your video located at `/app/views/todo_items/_todo_item.html.erb`. Or you can do:

```
<% @todo_items.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.content %>
<% end %>
```

---

In controller:

```
def index
  @todo_lists = TodoList.all
end
```

in view:

```
<% @todo_lists.each_with_index do |list, index| %>
  List <%= index + 1 %> todos:
  <%= render list.todo_items %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks it seems it worked but this will show all the item of all todo_list under each Todo_list, what i want to do is only show items of a list below it

Comment: i want something like in the "Show" page of that example
    <%= render @todo_list.todo_items %>
but the error now is "undefined method `todo_items' for nil:NilClass", i dont know what to put in the todo_list controller now

Comment: hmm it's not work, here is the picture https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6QMY6BEMRcFMUZxMnBXZG13NHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That's because of parameters you are sending to your link, @todo_list is nil in your case, you should send todo_list as params to render method (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9827701/985241). If you'll comment the link in your partial it should display the items correctly or pass it as described in link above and use it in partial. Anyway, that's different from what it was required in your question.